# Installing SSL Certificate on Amazon EC2 - Via CLI or http config

Tags: apache, ssl, amazon-ec2

I'm having problems installing a SSL cert on Amazon EC2, where the cert is there but it doesn't seem to be signed properly.

My question is: 
Amazon help wants me to use the CLI and upload that way, all the advice on here recommends configuring apache, installing openssl etc.

I'm doing both, but neither seem to be working.

Does anyone know which way is correct?

Comment: Are you installing an SSL certifcate on your instance or load balancer?

Comment: Which AWS CLI are you specifically referring to ?

Comment: On the Instance. Following these instructions: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/InstallCert.html

Comment: I've tried removing the cert installed via Apache and just using the version uploaded via the AWS CLI (from above instructions) and still getting the same error (this appears to be self signed certificate), I'm wondering if it's the bundle order, does anyone know if this is the correct order for commodo bundles on aws?  opy C:\server\EssentialSSLCA_2.crt + C:\server\ComodoUTNSGCCA.crt + C:\server\UTNAddTrustSGCCA.crt + C:\server\AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt C:\server\beek.ca-bundle